# RegionInfo throws exception in Windows 8.1 app

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, globalization

I have the following code:

```
 var culture = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture;
 var regionInfo = new RegionInfo(culture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName);
```

If `CurrenUiCulture` is Hebrew with ISOLanguageName "he" throws an exception

> The region name he should not correspond to neutral culture; a
>   specific culture name is required.

It works with other cultures like arab, spanish, chinese... What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`he` is a region neutral culture as shown by this code

```
new CultureInfo("he").IsNeutralCulture; // true
```

The `RegionInfo` that takes an `int` constructor words the exception in a different way that I found easier to understand.

```
new RegionInfo(new CultureInfo("he").LCID) // Culture ID 13 (0x000D) is a neutral culture; a region cannot be created from it.
```

Try with a more specific culture name, for example `he-il` for Israel.

`new RegionInfo("he-il")` does not throw an exception.

As for your other examples...

- `es` is both the region-neutral language code for Spanish AND the country code for Spain ([`RegionInfo` also accepts a country code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/atwc2921(v=vs.100).aspx)) so that's why it works
- `ar` is both the region-neutral language code for Arabic AND the country code for Argentina (so it "worked", but you will not get expected results)
- `zh` is the region-neutral code for Chinese and it should not have worked. Though if you tried `cn` it worked because it's the country code.

Comment: How to convert a neutral culture to specific one? I have the same problem.

Comment: There is no trivial conversion. One neutral culture corresponds to many specific ones.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need something more specific, like:

```
regionInfo = new RegionInfo("en-US")
```

I can't say which string literal you will need for hebrew language, but, as i did some research i couldn't even find the abbreviation "he" for hebrew... what i found is this list and there is no hebrew but "IL" for israel (It's for .NET 3.5):

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.regioninfo%28v=VS.90%29.aspx][1]

Hope this helps you.